# has_many :through, not reloaded/reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have three models, two of them are linked through a join model:

```
 # user.rb 
 has_many :user_cards
 has_many :cards, through: :user_cards


 # cards.rb
 has_many :user_cards
 has_many :users, through: user_cards

 # user_cards.rb
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :card
```

When I want to add a card to a user, I want to specify an attribute of a UserCard, that's why I create it this way:

```
 # example
 user.user_cards.create(card: card, paid: true)
```

- Then when I do `user.cards` it doesn't contain my new record.
- If I do `user.user_cards` it does contain my new record.

I need to call `user.cards.reset` (or reload). I don't like this solution because it requires another query.

Do you know how can I have reload|refresh|update `user.cards` without an additional query?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use `user.cards(true)` or `user.cards(force_reload = true)`.